# In Mirzapur, What did Kaleen Bhaiyya find in the compounder's phone?

Tags: plot-explanation, mirzapur

In season 1, after Munna kills the compounder. He visits his home and checks the compounder's phone. He is startled but the scene ends there.

At a later point, Maqbool breaks into the compounder's home and checks his phone too. He then immediately calls Kaleen Bhaiyya and asks him to check the call history.
An angry Kaleen Bhaiyya hands Munna his gun and asks for the lives of Guddu and Bablu.

What was there in the compounder's phone? Why did Kaleen Bhaiyya suddenly want Guddu and Bablu dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Guddu was constantly calling compounder, as he needed the pills.
Compounder by chance was attacking kaleen bhaiyya at the time.
So many missed calls would raise suspicion that Guddu was actually the one involved with compounder. Munna uses this to convince Maqbool and hence Kaleen bhayya.